# Conditional whitespace in output of regex replacement

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have a list of music titles, and from the live tracks I want to extract the event and - if present - the year. The output must be formatted as `event` `space` `year` or just `event`. You can do this very easily with a regular expression match, evaluate the groups, and add a space when neccesary. But can you do this also with a simple replacement?

```
myResult=Regex.replace(myTitle,".*(event1|event2|event3)\D*(\d+)?.*", "$1 $2" ,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

This works but has a superfluous space when there is no year. Like I said, there are many ways to do this differently, but I wonder if you can do it with a single regex replacement. Note that the input string might have a year number but without a leading space.

Comment: Have you looked at https://regexr.com/ ? Also, could you include some same input and expected output?

Answer (score 1):

If there is always at least a single space before the digits in group 2, you might write the pattern as:

```
.*(event1|event2|event3)(?:\D*?(\s\d+))?
```

And replace with `$1$2` which would also prevent an empty space if group 2 is empty.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9IIxds/1)

Or using `$1 $2` in the replacement if there are no more digits following:

```
.*(event1|event2|event3)\D*?(\d*)\D*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/B6PhJc/1)

Comment: I realize now that `.*(event1|event2|event3)(?:\D*(\d+))?.*` with output `$1$2` does not guarantee what is between event and year in the output.